# Display login success without adding to every page

Tags: php, html

So I want to add like a box that says that you have been logged in successfully, but I don't want to add the code to every page. How can I make it so that the code is added to the login page (which redirects you to the home page, or whatever)?

Comment: are you looking for a dynamic solution? something like a quick login form (username & password) that then sends them to a success page, that which reloaded the home page after 60 seconds or something? Or are you looking for a popup or something different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the $_POST global on the page what is the submit page of the login form. The most useful is when that is the index.php, which includes all the other active pages.

```
if( isset($_POST['loginname']) )
{
>>write out the welcome message<<
}
```

it means, that immediatelly before that was submitted the form with the loginname input field.
After that save the login event into a session (ex. `$_SESSION=$_POST['loginname']`), only this will accesible on all further pages. But on logout do not forget to clear that session.

Answer (score 0):

That depends on your login system structure but if you have a login box at the top of everypage for example there should be a script to process those logins without adding code to everypage other than a header include.

Again, depends on how your site is setup

If your question is how to send that information and store it from page to page, you would use _POST to send to login page, store the information in a session/cookie. Etc

Edit: if i am misunderstanding the question, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

The question is not really clear. Looks like you need to think of a include file which can have your success message and related processing.